# Power BI Report Server - change maximum size of uploaded file

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

Power BI Report Server allows uploading report files to the server up to 2GB in size.
The limit is set by default to 1GB [see details from the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/whats-new#large-file-uploaddownload)

> You can upload files up to 2 GB in size, though by default this limit is set to 1 GB in the Report Server settings in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). These files are stored in the database just as they are for SharePoint, and no special configuration for the SQL Server catalog is required.

How to locate and change the setting from default 1GB to 2GB?

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS connect to Reporting Services on [Power BI Reporting Server]

Once connected in SSMS

- select properties, go to advanced section
- change MaxFileSizeMb from default value of 1000 to desired new value

Comment: I did it. But nothing changed